# Fatal error: Call to undefined method MongoCollection::insertMany()?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have tried to insert Multiple Documents in one collection to Mongodb using Php but I got the Error..

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method MongoCollection::insertMany() in D:\xampp_1.8.3\htdocs\Mongo-PHP\trends.php on line 126
```

PHP CODE:

```
$con = new MongoClient();
            $db = $con->sample;
            $collection = $db->createCollection('trends');

            if($collection->insertMany([$doc1, $doc2])):
                echo "<h4>Trends Record Insert Successfully In \"trends\" table!!</h4>";
            endif;
```

In above Code `$doc1` and `$doc2` is my PHP Array.. how to fix that Error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such method like `insertMany()` in `MongoCollection` class you should use [batchInsert()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.batchinsert.php) instead.

Moreover, `MongoClient` class is deprecated use http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-manager.php instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try batchInsert();

Read this link with good and detailed info:
http://www.hgb-leipzig.de/~uklaus/PHP/mongocollection.batchinsert.html